# Remove <br>'s from the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

As the title says I have a string like this:

```
$string = "Hello World<br>hello world<br><br>";
```

I would like to get rid of the `<br>`s at the end of the string so it looks as follows:

```
$string = "Hello World<br>hello world";
```

I tried this:

```
preg_replace('/^(<br>)*/', "", $string);
```

but it didn't work.
Maybe someone knows the right regex.

Comment: Note your question says "now i want to get rid of the 's" ... put the `<br>` in backticks (`\``) so that it shows up :)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Do you want `<br>`'s inside the string to be converted to `\n` (newline) and `<br>`'s at the end of the string to be stripped? So in your example, the resulting string should be `"Hello World\nhello world"`? If so, you probably need two regexp-replaces, one for the newline case and another for the strip case. Please edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: no the resulting string should look like this "Hello World<br>hello world". the solution from NickAldwin and Alex Howansky does the tick. thanks again.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're close, you used ^ at the start of the regexp, which means "match the start of the string." You want $ at the end, which means, "Match the end of the string."

```
preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $string);
```

Comment: And for, `<br />`, this seems to work for me: `preg_replace('/(<br \/>)+$/', '', $string);`

Comment: how to find and replace last 4 character is <br> tag

Comment: If you want to see how this regex works -> https://regex101.com/r/L7gswR/1

Answer (score 13):

Just for anyone else who comes along this, like I, looking for a way to remove any all break tags from the end of a string, including:

```
<br> <br/> <br /> <br              /> <br      >
```

I used:

```
$string = preg_replace('#(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}$#i', '', $string);
```

to great effect. This will also strip them, if they have white-space between each. You'll need to adjust for any \n\r etc, if that's what you require.

Comment: Thank you! Your sollution worked great for me, but I need it also to strip them from the beginning of the string, do you know how can I do it?

Comment: I haven't had time to test it but this should remove them from the start of a string:

    $string = preg_replace('#^(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}#i', '', $string);

Comment: it can also be a lot easier: `(?:\s*<br *\/?>\s*)+$` for the end or `^(?:\s*<br *\/?>\s*)+` from the beginning that grills all the br tags with or without slash inside and also with any white space before the slash or before/after the tags

Answer (score 7):

I think, that the best solution for removing all spaces and BRs from the end of the string is this:

```
preg_replace('#(\s*<br\s*/?>)*\s*$#i', '', $string);
```

Test here:

```
$arr = [
  '<something>else that</needs>to <br>  <BR      />      <br/>  ',
  '<something>else that</needs>to <br>',
  '<something>else that</needs>to    <br/>  ',
  '<something>else that</needs>to     ',
  '<something>else that</needs>to<br/>',
  ];

foreach ($arr as $string) {
 var_dump(preg_replace('#(\s*<br\s*/?>)*\s*$#i', '', $string));
}
```

This prints:

```
test.php:11:string '<something>else that</needs>to' (length=30)
test.php:11:string '<something>else that</needs>to' (length=30)
test.php:11:string '<something>else that</needs>to' (length=30)
test.php:11:string '<something>else that</needs>to' (length=30)
test.php:11:string '<something>else that</needs>to' (length=30)
```

Comment: Be careful, if you have around 3000 <br> at the end, PHP throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

Try `preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', "", $string);`

EDIT: Oops, this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are powerful, but I think this case is more simple, **rtrim** should work

```
$string = rtrim($string,'<br>');
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. It will remove _any_ of the characters `<`, `b`, `r`, or `>`, in any order, from the end of the string, if present - so `I like rhubarb<br>` will become `I like rhuba` and `</footer>` will become `</foote`. rtrim has its uses but this is not one.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip

Answer (score -1):

You could try the strip_tags function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: As he mentioned he want only the end tags … so `strip_tags` wich removes all occurrences is not helpful.