# Remove <p>&nbsp;</p> from end of string?

Tags: php, regex, string

Maybe a newbie question:

I have a string like:

```
$string = '<p>this is what we need.</p><p>&nbsp</p>';
```

How can I remove the last characters, i.e. `<p>&nbsp</p>`, using PHP regex (not substr)?

I found a similar question here: [remove <br>'s from the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618082/remove-brs-from-the-end-of-a-string)
with solution: `preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $string);`

But changing this to: `preg_replace('/(<p>&nbsp;</p>)+$/', '', $string);`
does not work.

It throws `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'p'`

I guess I am missing some escaping? Of the <> or the slashes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please str_replace it will work.

Comment: Note that you won't need the `+` if there's only one occurrence at the end of the line (and depending on whether or not you want to remove just the last, or multiple occurrences).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the slash character as a regex delimiter and also as part of your regex (in the closing p tag) so you should escape it. So:

```
/(<p>&nbsp;</p>)+$/
```

should be

```
/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)+$/
```

And also it seems that this is not the kind of job for a regex, but it's your call.. [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) or [str_ireplace](http://php.net/str_ireplace) would do the job just fine

Comment: Or just change the delimiter to `#`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid right; and also another thing to notice: if these things need to remove that only from the end of the subject a regex that matches only the end (^ character used to mark the end) might help

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would like to use str_replace, but not all strings I get have a `<p>&nbsp</p>` in the end. That's why I thought I have to use regex. # How would you do it with str_replace then?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV try `str_ireplace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $string)`

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV are you by any chance trying to remove empty paragraphs from content generated with wordpress?

Comment: @mishu Thanks for pointing out `str_ireplace`, but it will replace all occurences of `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. There might be strings incoming with several <p>&nbsp;</p>. Anyways, I could check if last chars match and then use `substr` to remove them. # Wordpress? Nope, not at all :) Pure PHP. # Your answer is the best showing me the regex mistake I did :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple way you can do

```
$string = '<p>this is what we need.</p><p>&nbsp</p>';

$string = str_replace('<p>&nbsp</p>','',$string);
```

Comment: this is very simple way to remove <p>&nbsp</p>

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$string = '<p>this is what we need.</p><p>&nbsp</p>';
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>/"; 
$string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

This would replace all empty `<p>`, not just those containing `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

Not using regexes, but guaranteed to remove only the string when it is at the end:

```
$string = '<p>&nbsp</p><p>the previous and next &nbsp should remain</p><p>nbsp</p><p>this is what we need.</p><p>&nbsp</p><p>&nbsp</p><p>&nbsp</p><p>&nbsp</p>';
$lenString = strlen($string);
$remove = '<p>&nbsp</p>';
$lenRemove = strlen($remove);
while (strrpos($string, $remove) === $lenString - $lenRemove) {
  $string = substr($string, 0, -$lenRemove);
  $lenString = strlen($string);
}

echo $string, PHP_EOL;
```

this prints `<p>&nbsp</p><p>the previous and next &nbsp should remain</p><p>nbsp</p><p>this is what we need.</p>`

Answer (score 0):

A good way to deal with slashes when you proceed on html content (or url) is to use other delimiters than slashes, example:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?><p>&nbsp;</p>)+$~', '', $string);
```

then you don't need to escape the slashes.

Note that you can delete all that is useless with:

```
$result = preg_replace('~
 (?>
    <(\w++)[^>]*+>(?>\s++|&nbsp;|<br\s*+/?>)*</\1>  # empty tags
   |                                                # OR
    (?>\s++|&nbsp;|<br\s*+/?>)+                     # white spaces, br, &nbsp;
 )+$
                        ~xi', '', $string);
```