# PHP: How to remove all occurrences of linebreaks at the end of a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

how can I remove all occurrences of linebreaks at the end of a string.

```
$string = "Hello<br/>my Text<br> <br/> <br /> <br              /> <br      >";
```

I would like to get this result: `Hello<br/>my Text`

This didn't help, as 
`$string = preg_replace('#(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}$#i', '', $string);` 
didn't work.

Here is a similar post that didn't solve my problem though.
[remove <br>'s from the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618082/remove-brs-from-the-end-of-a-string)

Thank you very much
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job.
`$string=preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', trim($string)); 
echo preg_replace('#(?:(?: *)?<br */?>)+$#', '', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

This is how the regex was built:

```
#<br>#                   // bare <br>
#<br */?>#               // <br> with internal spaces and maybe a slash
#(?: *)?<br */?>#        // maybe there are spaces in front
#(?: *)?<br */?>$#       // at the end of the line
#(?:(?: *)?<br */?>)+$#  // the whole thing one or more times at the end of the line
```

so:

```
echo preg_replace('#(?:(?: *)?<br */?>)+$#', '', 'Hello<br/>my Text<br> <br/> <br /> <br              /> <br      >');
// Output: Hello<br/>my Text
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/e9-d6f9-3Za3SUuK) is your [and my] friend.

Comment: It fails with this string!

`$string="
My Text 1<br />
<br />
My Text 2<br />
<br />
<br>
<br>
<br />
<br />";`


Why??

Comment: Debuggex says it matches with the above - strange!

Comment: @TomSenner Works for me in PHP too. :I

Comment: @TomSenner Hey there, I'm the creator of Debuggex. Can you link me to an example of the incorrect behavior? I can't reproduce it. http://www.debuggex.com/r/lBbjfsCoL6oE3Y5n/0 correctly matches the trailing tags.

Comment: @SergiuToarca it seems to be working as expected in PHP, but while I've got your attention: the textarea on the 'share on StackOverflow' page is `<textarea rows="6" cols="80" disabled>` which makes it impossible to select or copy text from it without going to the page source. [at least in Firefox]

Comment: @SergiuToarca Thanks! Super-awesome tool, btw. Makes regular expressions *so much easier* to create. :D

Comment: `<?PHP

// MY PHP Version 5.3.27

$string="
My Text 1<br />
<br />
My Text 2<br />
<br />
<br>
<br>
<br />
<br />";


echo preg_replace('#(?:(?: *)?<br */?>)+$#', '', $string); // still echoes all the above br-tags

?>`

Comment: @Sergiu Toarca
I'm not quite sure wheather the incorrect behavier is on side of debuggex or PHP. But try with my code above please.

Comment: @TomSenner I get `My Text 1<br /> <br /> My Text 2` as output, is this not the expected result? I'm running php 5.3.3

Comment: @Sammitch This output is expected and also my wanted result, but it's not working for me...I'll check again and get back to you.

Comment: @Sammitch OK. In PHP your solution is only working for me if I remove all unnecesary whitespaces before: So here's the code that did the job for me.

`$string=preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $string);
echo preg_replace('#(?:(?: *)?<br */?>)+$#', '', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is not really intended for DOM-parsing, but if you need/choose to use it, this should do it:

```
preg_replace('/<br *\/?>(?!\w)/', '', $string);
```

That removes any `<br />` tag (with our without space or self-closing slash) that is not immediately followed by an alphanumeric character, hence the first one is preserved.

That, though, highlights the limitations of REGEX for problems such as this. You might wish to keep a tag that is not followed by an alphanumeric character. In that case, there's not a lot REGEX can offer. A DOM-parser, in contrast, could iteratively remove the trailing tags by virtue of each being the last-child of the container.

You will still be left with the spaces between the removed tags, but you can then just `trim()` the result or run a further REGEX on it:

```
preg_replace('/\s*$/', '', $string);
```

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/<br *\/?>(?!\w)/g', '', $string);`
did output nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Apologies - too much JavaScript lately. Try now.