# jQuery text editor (jqte) adds automatic <br> tag?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, jqte

For some reason jqte is automatically adding an html break at the end of the textarea and I don't know how to get rid of it.

**Source:**

```
<div>
<textarea class="about_me" name="about_me" value="">
Just some test text.&lt;br&gt;
</textarea>
</div>
```

From the testing I've done, these HTML entities are added whether there is anything in the textarea or not. I checked the demo on [jqueryte.com/demos](http://jqueryte.com/demos) and these tags aren't there.

```
$(function() {
    $(".about_me").jqte({
        link: false, 
        unlink: false, 
        source: false, 
        rule: false, 
        sub: false, 
        sup: false,
        outdent: false,
        indent: false,
        remove: false
    });
});
```

The plugin version I have is 1.4.0 (latest). Even if I do `br: false` they still show up. I've also tested in IE and firefox but both have the issue.

**EDIT :**
I still don't know the cause, but I do know the `<br>` is added when pressing the spacebar.

Comment: Changed to `tinyMCE` instead.

Comment: I faced the same problem... when parsing the text you could use something like... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618082/remove-brs-from-the-end-of-a-string/30422350#30422350

Comment: Did you try setting br to false? on the constructor?

Comment: @Ares - Yes, it is mentioned in the question.